# RavenDB paging via cursor

Tags: ravendb

Paging in RavenDB is done via skip+take. This is default implementation I'm happy with most of the time. However for frequently changing data I want paging via a cursor. The cursor/after parameter specifies which was the last record displayed and where the list should continue on the next page.
This should work for data which can be dynamically sorted, so the sorting parameter is not fixed.

github is doing it this way on the "stars" page for example: [https://github.com/[username]?after=Y3Vyc29&tab=stars](https://github.com/%5Busername%5D?after=Y3Vyc29&tab=stars)

Any ideas how to achieve this in RavenDB?

Answer (score 2):

there is no cursor pagination in RavenDB.
But you can use the 'last-modified to continuously iterate on frequently changing data.

```
from Orders as o
where o.'@metadata'.'@last-modified' > "2018-08-28:12:11" 
order by o.'@metadata'.'@last-modified'
select {
    A: o["@metadata"]["@last-modified"]
}.
```

---

You can also use [`Subscription`](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.2/csharp/client-api/data-subscriptions/creation/how-to-create-data-subscription)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sadly this won't work as this should work for data which can be dynamically sorted.